# Preventing a message from being sent in android

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

I know I can detect a message that is being sent using the following code

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"),true, myObserver);
```

what I need to know, is it possible to prevent it from going out or suspend it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not possible unless you are the Messaging application that the user typed the message in to (then you could do whatever you want with it, including not send)

However if the user is using the stock Messaging app or another 3rd party one there is not a way for a different application to try to stop the SMS from being sent (this ability would almost certainly get abused.)

I think there are apps meant for use when driving that will block incoming texts from being shown to user, maybe look in to those, if there is a way to do outgoing maybe they'll have figured it out. I don't think it is going to be possible on a stock device though.